# Toggling API call by a stream

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactive-programming, reactivex

Here:

```
import Rx from 'rxjs';

function fakeApi(name, delay, response) {
  return new Rx.Observable(observer => {
    console.log(`${name}: Request.`)
    let running = true;
    const id = setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(`${name}: Response.`)
      running = false;
      observer.next(response);
      observer.complete();
    }, delay);
    return () => {
      if(running) console.log(`${name}: Cancel.`)
      clearTimeout(id);
    }
  })
}

function apiSearch() { return fakeApi('Search', 4000, "This is a result of the search."); }


//============================================================

const messages$ = new Rx.Subject();

const toggle$ = messages$.filter(m => m === 'toggle');

const searchDone$ = toggle$.flatMap(() => 
  apiSearch().takeUntil(toggle$)
);

searchDone$.subscribe(m => console.log('Subscriber:', m))

setTimeout(() => {
  // This one starts the API call.
  toggle$.next('toggle'); 
}, 2000)

setTimeout(() => {
  // This one should only cancel the API call in progress, not to start a new one.
  toggle$.next('toggle'); 
}, 3000)

setTimeout(() => {
  // And this should start a new request again...
  toggle$.next('toggle'); 
}, 9000)
```

my intent is to start the API call and stop it when it is in progress by the same `toggle$` signal. Problem with the code is that `toggle$` starts a new API call every time. I would like it not to start the new call when there is one already running, just to stop the one which is already in progress. Some way should I "unsubscribe" the outermost `flatMap` from `toggle$` stream while `apiSearch()` is running. I guess that there is a need to restructure the code to achieve the behaviour... What is the RxJS way of doing that?

**UPDATE:** After some more investigations and user guide lookups, I came with this:

```
const searchDone$ = toggle$.take(1).flatMap(() =>
  apiSearch().takeUntil(toggle$)
).repeat()
```

Works like it should. Still feels cryptic a little bit. Is this how you RxJS guys would solve it?

Comment: If you could draw a simple marble diagram it might be easier to help you out :). With paint or an equivalent, or even by hand and just take a picture, really something simple

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution will work only once since you're using `take(1)`. You could do it like this:

```
const searchDone$ = toggle$
    .let(observable => {
        let pending;

        return observable
            .switchMap(() => {
                let innerObs;

                if (pending) {
                    innerObs = Observable.empty();
                } else {
                    pending = innerObs = apiSearch();
                }

                return innerObs.finally(() => pending = null);
            });
    });
```

I'm using `let()` only to wrap `pending` without declaring it in parent scope. The `switchMap()` operator unsubscribes for you automatically without using `take*()`.

The output with your test `setTimeout`s will be as follows:

```
Search: Request.
Search: Cancel.
Search: Request.
Search: Response.
Subscriber: This is a result of the search.
```